# Combing queries and arraying results

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Okay essentially what I'm trying to achieve is to combine the first query with the second one the trouble I'm having is that I'm unable to array out the results from the first query to then use in the second one. Here is my first query what this achieves is that it selects all the room subjects from my users which typically look like this, `welcome to my #room hope you #enjoy` once is selects one it will then strip the subject of the words and will only keep the hash-tags for example it will keep `#room` and `#enjoy` once its goes through and selects all the hash-tags from all of the room subjects it will then order them from how frequent they are used among subjects of all users.

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT subject FROM `users`");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

$freqDist = [];
foreach($results as $row)
{
        $words = explode(" ", $row);
        foreach($words as $w)
        {
                if (array_key_exists($w, $freqDist))
                        $freqDist[$w]++;
                else
                        $freqDist[$w] = 1;
        }
}
arsort($freqDist);

foreach($freqDist as $word => $count)
{
    if (strpos($word, '#') !== FALSE)
        echo "$word: $count\n";
    else
        echo "$word: does not contain hashtag, DROPPED\n";
}
```

Now what I'm trying to achieve here is that I'm trying to array out the results from the above query so then I can perform an action on each hash-tag which is grabbed from above. Below I have included the code and essentially the problem I face lies solely on this line `$all = array("hashtag1", "hashtag2", "hashtag3");` as what I'm trying to achieve is instead of typing in directly the hash-tags I want to perform the action on I would want them to be grabbed via using the above query.

```
$all = array("hashtag1", "hashtag2", "hashtag3");
    $trending = $all;
    foreach($trending as $tags)
    { 
    $sql =  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `subject` LIKE '%$tags%'");
        $sums =  mysql_query("SELECT SUM(viewers) AS viewers FROM `users` WHERE `subject` LIKE '%$tags%'");
            $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);
            $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
            $sum = mysql_fetch_assoc($sums);
    }
```

So again just to outline my problem I'm trying to grab the results from the first query and use them as an array with the second query. I apologise for the length of this question I just assumed it would help you better understand my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding, you want to store the hashtag value in an array. if so then just update your foreach()

```
$hashWord =  array();
foreach($freqDist as $word => $count)
{
    if (strpos($word, '#') !== FALSE)
        echo "$word: $count\n";
        $hashWord[] = $word;
    else
        echo "$word: does not contain hashtag, DROPPED\n";
}
```